# Cannot find sub-field

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this data on my `mongodb` database:

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3, "bU0bX4VEAMnW7AJ28wXcoA=="),
    "online" : false,
    "money" : 0,
    "rank" : "USER",
    "ban" : {
        "end" : NumberLong("3027259780628"),
        "reason" : "hello"
    } 
}
```

and I use this code to access to the `ban.end` sub-field saved in it:

```
final Document doc = collcetion.find(new Document("_id", myId)).
                              projection(Projections.include("ban.end"));
System.out.println(doc); // here is all ok. 
                         // It print out the _id with the 
                         // ban and the end values.
final long a = doc.getLong("ban.end"); // nullptr exception because 
                                       // I tryied to do this: 
long a = (Long) null;
```

Is there any way to fix the `null pointer` reported above? I think I failed something with `mongodb`, I'm not sure in using `ban.end` as field name.

I already tried to get, for example, the `money` value and it works.

Comment: `I tryied to do this: long a = (Long) null;` Why?? That wouldn't even compile so I'm not sure how you think that's generating a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`getLong` returns a `Long`, not a `long`.  See http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/Document.html#getLong-java.lang.Object-.

In other words, you're getting the nullpointer because you're implicitly unboxing it.  Just use

```
final long a = doc.getLong("ban.end");
```

instead, the handle the null case separately.

Comment: The point is that it returns always null and it should returns a value. Is that the problem, I didn't have to handle the result.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure in using "ban.end" as field name.

Sadly, you are. You need to get the `ban` objcect first, before you could access its `end` attribute.

The logic remains the same for whatever versions.

code in `3.0.4` version of the `java` driver,

```
DBCursor docs = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", myId), 
                                     new BasicDBObject("ban.end", 1));
while (docs.hasNext())
{
  BasicDBObject banObj = (BasicDBObject) docs.next().get("ban");
  long end = banObj.getLong("end");
  System.out.println(end);
}
```